# ViewPager + FragmentPagerAdapter + Update Fragment?

Tags: java, android

Na implementação de uma SlidingTabs utilizando as classes SlidingTabLayout e SlidingTabStrip fornecidas pelo site do Android Dev + ViewPager + FragmentPagerAdapter quando os dados são atualizados nos Fragments que foram criados pelo FragmentPagerAdapter oque devo fazer para atualizar eles na tela, no meu projeto não atualiza parece que o FragmentPagerAdapter não esta recriando os fragments internos

Tenho que usar algum notify ou updatechange ou algo parecido?

**Lista de Repositórios populares em Java fornecidos pelo API.GIT**
[image]

**Lista de Pulls e Issues do Repositório clicado na primeira tela**
[image]

**Voltando a primeira tela para selecionar outro Repositório**
[image]

**O Sliding que deveria mostrar a nova lista de Pulls e Issues do novo Repositorio selecionado fica vazia.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consegui corrigir o problema mudando o *Adapter* do tipo `FragmentPagerAdapter` para `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Não sei se essa seria a única solução mas funcionou.